# How to get (x,y) of circle surface?

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to draw line over all circle surface, my current shape look like:

[image]

My wrong attempt:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        g.drawLine(xCenter - clockRadius + i , yCenter - clockRadius + i, xCenter - clockRadius + i + 5,
                yCenter - clockRadius + i + 5);
    }
```

I'm trying to draw a full clock :

[image]

Comment: Maybe this link will help you to start [Analog-clock-in-applet](https://www.javatpoint.com/Analog-clock-in-applet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate points over 360 degree not just 24, so you have the radius and angel rotation (angel rotation from 0 to 360) to get the proper point of (x,y) we need to multiply  sin or cos of *angel*  with radius.

[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
        int x = (int) (clockRadius * Math.cos(i)) + xCenter;
        int y = (int) (clockRadius * Math.sin(i)) + yCenter;
        g.drawLine(x, y, x + 5, y + 5);
    }
```

**Note:** for better result you may need to develop two loops, one for right (180) part and another for left (180) part.

Edit: to get the right direction you need to check for angel e.g:

```
int xV = 0, yV = 0;
if (i <= 90){
   xV = 5;
   yV = 5;
 }
```

Comment: no need to do that, you only need to loop 1/4 of the circle and mirror the remaining 3 points around the center

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for cosinus and sinus.

[image: circle with cos and sin]

Your clock is a circle, and you can easily translate your steps into degrees on that circle. If you want to have 24 steps, 12 would be 180° (or π) and 24 would be 360°, or 2π. So to get the correct angles for each index, just devide 2π (360°) by 24 and multiply it by the current index. Then feed that resulting angle to the cos and sin functions, which give you the x and y coordinates respectively:

```
double x = Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / 24 * i);
double y = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / 24 * i);
```

Of course you can optimize the 2 and the 24 into one constant that you define somewhere and then use in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want to draw small segments - ticks, centered at circumference and directed from the circle center. In this case use trigonometry alike hour hands drawing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   double ang = i * Math.Pi / 12;
   g.drawLine((int) (xCenter + (clockRadius - 5) * Math.Cos(ang)), 
             (int) (yCenter + (clockRadius - 5) * Math.Sin(ang)), 
             (int) (xCenter + (clockRadius + 5) * Math.Cos(ang)), 
             (int) (yCenter + (clockRadius + 5) * Math.Sin(ang))); 
}
```

Comment: Downvoted, because this will draw 24° on a 360° circle, you have to devide by 24 as well. (Will upvote when fixed.)

Comment: @Max Vollmer Thanks, missed that coefficient (really 2/24) when was correcting from degrees to radians.